# Is there a ReSharper attribute for ASP.NET Core View Components location?

Tags: asp.net-core, resharper

I am using [Feature Slices in ASP.NET Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx) and would like to put View Components in the same folder as my views.

For ReSharper, you can set attributes like this, for view location:

```
[assembly: AspMvcViewLocationFormat(@"~\Features\{1}\{0}.cshtml")]
[assembly: AspMvcViewLocationFormat(@"~\Features\Shared\{0}.cshtml")]
```

This makes ReSharper correctly deduce the location of the views, for view generation and navigation. This does not work for View Components, however.

Is there any way to get the same effect for View Components?